# Slicing key words to become a new category column in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = pd.Series(['ABC Company, UK', 'CDE Company, US', 'CN DEF Company'])
data
```

[out]

```
0    ABC Company, UK
1    CDE Company, US
2     CN DEF Company
dtype: object
```

How to add another column to become a dataframe that is named 'Region' to convert from UK to United Kindom, US to United States, and CN to China in this column?

I guess to use a dictionary function to do that?

Comment: You answered your question already. "I guess to use a dictionary function to do that?"

Comment: Where is the data coming from before you're adding it into the series? It would be hard to get the countries out of the input you've given.

Comment: You can use this [link of country codes in CSV form](https://gist.github.com/HarishChaudhari/4680482). Download it and convert to a dictionary or dataframe.

Comment: I just made some examples. I understand that I need to do a list of the pair relationship but can you let me know how to pair them into the column?

Comment: Thank you @ W Stokvis. This is very helpful! But how to code them... I am a newbie...

Comment: If the country code is available separately for each row - then a lookup table is great as suggested (you've already got an answer that addresses that)... However, if your only source of what could be a country code is in your data, then you need to come up with some firm rules on how to reliably extract it from that... Unless it's only 3 countries and CN is always the first two letters or UK/US is always the last two etc... that's going to be quite an experimental thing you'll have to play with as only you have access to your real data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data, you can do:

```
data = data.str.split(pat=',', expand=True)

countries = {'UK':'United Kingdom',
                 'US':'United States',
                 'CN':'China'}

data[1] = data[1].map(coyntries)

data = data.str.cat([0, 1], sep=',')
```

Comment: Hi Prayson, it says AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str' ?

Comment: Then your data is not a Series but DataFrame. You need to select that column then, e.g. data['columnName'] instead of just data.

Comment: What do you see when you print(data.columns)?

Answer (score 1):

If you split the code out of your column first, you can map using a dictionary:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'country_code':['UK','US','CN']})

>>> countries = {'UK':'United Kingdom',
                 'US':'United States',
                 'CN':'China'}

>>> df['country_name'] = df['country_code'].map(countries)

>>> df

  country_code    country_name
0           UK  United Kingdom
1           US   United States
2           CN           China
```